# FileStream dosen´t work in actionscript 3 (Adobe Air)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have a little problem here.. The code itself dosen´t get any errors, but it will not write to the .txt file... Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Here is my code:

```
test_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leggtil);

function leggtil(e:MouseEvent) {

var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt"); 
var fileStream = new FileStream(); 
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); 

var outputString:String = "test";  

fileStream.writeUTFBytes(outputString); 
fileStream.close(); 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code and it worked on my machine.

I believe that the code is working for you, but you're not aware of where the file has been written. Check your documents folder. In Windows, this would be `C:\Users\[your user name]\Documents\`. If you browse to that folder, you should see a file there named `test.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! i found it. But i have one more question, can i add text to the already created file? like if it is written "test" in the document, is it possible to write a new line in the same document and write another string?

Comment: FileMode.WRITE = write, FileMode.APPEND = append.